# Ubuntu login screen seems like 22.04 after updating to 23.04

Tags: updates, 22.04, login, login-screen, 23.04

I updated Ubuntu 22.04 to 23.04. But after booting up. The login screen seems like it is from 22.04. When I suspend and see the login page it seems like 23.04. And the graphics of buttons at login screen is a little bit broken too when I first booted up not suspended.

When suspended:
[image: When suspended]

Login screen:
[image: Login screen]

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall gnome-shell-common package. And if you are using gdm-settings, change shell theme to Default.

Comment: Reinstalled gnome-shell-common and I am not using gdm-settings to. But issue is not resolved.

Comment: sudo update-alternatives  --auto gdm-theme.gresource

Or

sudo update-alternatives  --auto gdm3-theme.gresource